# What other maintenance items are good to do if a transmission is dropped?

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, maintenance, suburban

My car (2005 Suburban with 130,000 miles) has transmission issues (clanging noise coming from around the flexplate).  Likely the transmission is going to need to be dropped, and unfortunately I'll have to take it somewhere as I'm not about to attempt this myself!  Can you think of any good maintenance items I can direct my mechanic to perform outside of my transmission issue?

One example that I'm not even sure is valid is to change the crankshaft bearing.

Thanks!

Comment: crankshafts have more than one bearing - would you be considering changing them all?

Comment: Just the easy ones that would be easy to get at with the transmission out.

Comment: The LS based engines are 250,000 mile engines (easy) with proper maintenance (oil changed, coolant, etc). There's an old saying, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it." I think it applies in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I would replace the front seal on the transmission, and if your engine has a one piece rear main seal, I would replace it as well.

Answer (score 3):

You had not mentioned if it was a manual or auto, but if manual and the transmission has to come out, only makes sense to be sure to check the clutch components.

It is arguable at 130K an OEM clutch plate is near new at this point, my smaller car was fine at that same mileage.
But the finger springs may be worth a change even if they don't appear worn. I would also check the flywheel face, and have it re-machined if there was any wear.

I would say at 130k the pilot bearing and the throw bearing should be changed regardless.

Also on many cars, not sure about the suburban, but jeep Cherokee and ford escort have freeze plugs behind the clutch, if so id give it a real hard look and judge if it needs to be replaced.

Unfortunately there are many variables, including your wallet, and less obvious the effort of your mechanic when it comes to these things..